# Css/HTML Works in one directory and not in another

Tags: html, css, permissions

I'm trying to do some basic html/css and it doesn't work in one directory of my computer but works on all other directory's. (I'm using a mac and tried on a user level root sites folder and the page does not show up properly.) If i move the folder with all of my files in it (exact same files as in the sites folder) to another directory it shows up properly and works fine..Is there an issue with permissions or something that would cause this?

Thanks!

Code as requested:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <p>Donec sollicitudin mi et magna. Proin non est. Vestibulum diam. Quisque in enim. Sed id dui. Nunc nec sapien. Nulla lacus. Quisque in ante vel nunc semper pellentesque. Nam sit amet lacus sit amet ipsum auctor eleifend. Quisque vitae justo eu neque mattis pellentesque. Suspendisse tristique. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque hendrerit tristique turpis. Pellentesque eget mi. Vestibulum a lacus.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
          <p>Donec sollicitudin mi et magna. Proin non est. Vestibulum diam. Quisque in enim. Sed id dui. Nunc nec sapien. Nulla lacus. Quisque in ante vel nunc semper pellentesque. Nam sit amet lacus sit amet ipsum auctor eleifend. Quisque vitae justo eu neque mattis pellentesque. Suspendisse tristique. Nulla facilisi. Pellentesque hendrerit tristique turpis. Pellentesque eget mi. Vestibulum a lacus.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Within the sites folder it comes up as 2 rows instead of 2 columns and outside of my sites folder it comes out properly as 2 columns instead of 2 rows.

Comment: Can you give us some code, say us what doesn't work, and the paths...?

Comment: I'm guessing you need to do the styles relative to the css file (not the file accessing it). But without a clear example of what is wrong this is a complete guess as your explanation isn't very clear either

Comment: I'm using the basic Bootstrap Template and the bootstrap framework. There shouldn't be a reason it's not working except with permissions...

Comment: Added example and issue, if you need a screen shot i can provide it!

Comment: so the page containing the above html is in same directory as your css folder?

Comment: @Pete my folder looks like this http://cl.ly/image/002c3u47023D